# How do I add a command where it bans the user in all the servers the bot is in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command using discord.js  that would execute a command on multiple servers.
this is what I have done so far.

```
if (isCommand('globalban', message)) {
if(!member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Staff')) 
   return message.reply("You can't use this command.");
var targetID = args[1]; // this is the targets UserID

if (!targetID)
   return message.channel.send("Please provide the targets ID");
//rest of code goes here. 


return;
}
```

I am not sure on how to continue this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.ban(targetID))`

Comment: On my console i got "a.ban is not a function"

Comment: sorry, my bad. `a.members.cache.ban(targetID)`

Comment: ```client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.cache.ban(targetID))
                                                 ^
TypeError: a.members.cache.ban is not a function
```
Still not working.

Comment: Alright i figured it out it was ```a.members.ban(targetID)```

Answer (score 0):

well, just have the bot loop through all the guilds it's in and search for that user. I could try giving you some code, but idk what version of discord.js you are using.

EDIT: in discord.js v12 --->

`client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.cache.get(targetID.)ban()`

Comment: I am using discord.js V12

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.cache.get(targetID.)ban() `

Answer (score 0):

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Owner = require("../config.json")

module.exports = {
    name: "globalban",
    description: "bans the user from all servers the bot is in",
    aliases: "gb",
    execute(message, args, client){

        const targetID = args[0];
        const reason = args.slice(0).join(' ')
        if(!message.author === Owner) return message.channel.send("You need to be bot owner to use this command");
        
        else{
        client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.ban(targetID));
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Successfully banned`)
        .setDescription(`I have successfully banned ${targetID.tag} from all servers`)
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/764396593964122132.gif?v=1")
        message.channel.send(embed)

        const dmembed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("You have been banned from all the servers i am in")
        .setDescription('Your Crime was `${reason}`. If you want to apeal, You may join [Appeal Server by Clicking here](https://discord.gg/ZWWYy37atN)')
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        message.targetID.send(embed)
        }
    }
}
```